# Accessing dynamically added properties in Spring @RequestBody

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a post mapping like below:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/profiles/{profileId}/verify/")
public Response getVerificationInformation (
    @RequestBody VerificationBody body) {
    ... do something with the body
    ... call function A with body object
}
```

And later on at function A, I am accessing the body object for a few attributes.

Also, in the front-end, I am modifying the JSON object (I am adding another property) that hits this post mapping.

For example,

```
{
    "name" : "Example",
    "profileId" : "123",
    // and I am dynamically adding an attribute 'country'
    "country" : "US"
}
```

The problem is at function A, I have no means to get information about the dynamically added attribute (in this case 'country').

Declaring a getter for dynamically added properties is not ideal because there are many properties being dynamically added.

I have tried something in the direction of @JsonAnySetter and @JsonAnyGetter but I am getting 400. And I am looking for other solutions.

Please help and thank you in advance! (I simplified a few names of variables and functions but I hope it's not too hard to understand).

---

VerificationBody can be thought of as below:

```
public class VerificationBody {
    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    String name,
    @JsonProperty(value = "profileId")
    Long profileId,
    // ... it does not include country
}
```

---

Managed to fix the 400 issue and I am able to get the properties through JsonAnyGetter and JsonAnySetter.

Comment: If that is the case, why not use a `Map` for `RequestBody`?

Comment: what's inside `VerificationBody `? Please share the class.

Comment: @Prashant I am working on a rather big project and I am quite reluctant to change the request body type because it would be a big refactor.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati answered on the question

Comment: *"I have tried something in the direction of `@JsonAnySetter` and `@JsonAnyGetter` but I am getting 400"* Then figure out why you're getting 400, because `@JsonAnySetter` and `@JsonAnyGetter` is the **right answer**. Look at the stacktrace of the error causing the 400.

Answer (score 2):

Your `VerificationBody` class could be something like below:

```
class VerificationBody {
private String prop1;
//other properties & their getters and setter

private Map<String, ? extends Object> otherProps;
// getter setters for  otherProps

}
```

This will allow you to always receive additional properties without any issues with extension.

Comment: Unfortunately, when modifying the JSON in front-end, I am not able to add it to other Map like otherProps, but it will be simply appended to the JSON object like in the above example. Maybe I can change this behaviour but I am quite reluctant to do that.

Comment: Or did you mean to annotate otherProps with something else like @JsonAnySetter?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HashMap` something like this to tackle this kind of problem :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profiles/{profileId}/verify/", headers = "Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void verifyBody(@RequestBody HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> requestData) {

HashMap<String, String> customerInfo = requestData.get("verificationBody");
String param1 = customerInfo.get("param1");
//TODO now do whatever you want to do.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I am working on a rather big project and I am quite reluctant to change the request body type because it would be a big refactor.

Answer (score 2):

The annotation for the request body is @RequestBody. As the request body is a key-value pair, it will be wise to declare it as a Map.

```
@PostMapping("/blog")
public Blog create(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body){...}
```

To extract the respective keys and their values:

```
String id = body.get("id");
String title = body.get("title");
String content = body.get("content");
```

Try with this link

https://medium.com/better-programming/building-a-spring-boot-rest-api-part-ii-7ff1e4384b0b

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I am working on a rather big project and I am quite reluctant to change the request body type because it would be a big refactor.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is your JSON string is invalid, a valid one is supposed to look like below:

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "profileId": "123",
  "country": "US"
}
```

Please ensure that every **key** is double-quoted, or you will get **400 Bad Request** while serializing the request body to your POJO by using `Jackson`.

BTW, I'm using Spring Boot and I can reproduce getting HTTP status code 400 by your code snippet with the **invalid** JSON string as payload.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the double quotes. Also it was working til I added JsonAnySetter so it believe that is the issue. Will update the question to include double quotes! Thank you.

Comment: @seokhoonlee OK! But I also tested the your code with valid JSON string, it worked fine! Therefore, I cannot reproduce 400 Bad Request again.

Comment: yes the project is quite big so there are many layers of hidden information. I think the culprit is `spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES=true`. Thank you for exploring! :)

Comment: @seokhoonlee Yes! After adding this setting into application.properties, I got 400 now with error message - **JSON parse error: Unrecognized field \"country\"...**.

Comment: Yeah but the sad thing is that I may not be able to change this config because it affects json deserialization in other places. So I might have to look at other solutions. Thank you anyways :D

Comment: @seokhoonlee If you cannot set the `spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` to be `false`, mybe you can try to add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on class `VerificationBody`;

Answer (score 0):

You can try modify `VerificationBody` class like this:

```java
public class VerificationBody {
    private String name;
    private Long profileId;

    // getters & setters
}
```

`getVerificationInformation` class like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/profiles/{profileId}/verify/",
             consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
             produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Response getVerificationInformation (
    @RequestBody VerificationBody body) {
```

Comment: I don't get how this addresses the issue of accessing country property which is added dynamically.